# marshmallow-sqlalchemy giving syntax error

Tags: python, python-3.6, marshmallow, function-parameter

After installing `marshmallow-sqlalchemy` in python 3.5 it is showing me syntax error.

I had install it using follow command `pip install marshmallow-sqlalchemy`.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import flask_app
  File "/var/www/html/mswipe-banner/mswipe-banner/app/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    from .models import *
  File "/var/www/html/mswipe-banner/mswipe-banner/app/models/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .banner import *
  File "/var/www/html/mswipe-banner/mswipe-banner/app/models/banner.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base_model import *
  File "/var/www/html/mswipe-banner/mswipe-banner/app/models/base_model.py", line 1, in <module>
    from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow
  File "/var/www/html/mswipe-banner/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_marshmallow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from . import sqla
  File "/var/www/html/mswipe-banner/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask_marshmallow/sqla.py", line 13, in <module>
    import marshmallow_sqlalchemy as msqla
  File "/var/www/html/mswipe-banner/lib/python3.5/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .schema import TableSchemaOpts, ModelSchemaOpts, TableSchema, ModelSchema
  File "/var/www/html/mswipe-banner/lib/python3.5/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/schema.py", line 3, in <module>
    from .convert import ModelConverter
  File "/var/www/html/mswipe-banner/lib/python3.5/site-packages/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py", line 80
    ):
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Thank you

Comment: @suiwenfeng I don't what are you talking about. I just installed it using normal command `pip install`. I have import it into python file that is mentioned in error.

Comment: @suiwenfeng I think your not able to understand the error. If it won't get the package the it would had said it in error not syntax error. I have made python 3.6 environment. So I don't need to use `pip3`. I would request you to please read the error.

Comment: @Avi so your problem still exists on python3.6? can you paste version of marshmallow-sqlalchemy AND flask if possible.

Comment: @snakecharmerb it is working for me after downgrade. But I want know the exact reason why it is giving syntax error. What is major change between python3.5 to python3.6 that is breaking the syntax.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The installation fails because marshmallow-sqlalchemy [no longer supports](https://marshmallow-sqlalchemy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id3) Python 3.5.  The last version to support Python 3.5 is version 18.0, which must be installed explicitly.

The particular error in the traceback is caused by [this](https://github.com/marshmallow-code/marshmallow-sqlalchemy/blob/abf13441214e0ccd13c93cbcac493c065042cace/src/marshmallow_sqlalchemy/convert.py#L71) function declaration:

```
def fields_for_model(
    self,
    model,
    *,
    include_fk=False,
    fields=None,
    exclude=None,
    base_fields=None,
    dict_cls=dict,
):
```

Python 3.6 included a [change](https://bugs.python.org/issue9232) to permit trailing commas in function parameter lists.  Prior to this change, these signatures were legal:

```
>>> def f(a, b, c=1,):pass
... 
>>> def f(a, b, *, c=1):pass
... 
>>>
```

but this was not

```
>>> def f(a, b, *, c=1,):pass
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    def f(a, b, *, c=1,):pass
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

The `*` in the middle of the parameter list - indicating the start of keyword-only parameters - was added to the above marshmallow-sqlalchemy function signature after version 18, as part of the process of dropping 2.7 and 3.5 compatability.

Comment: Thank you so much for such as perfect explanation helping them with proper link.